# jQuery pre/append only within parent class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I have a page with lots of repeated items (a list of hotels)

I'm using optimizely and I'm trying to move elements around with in each hotel.

Every time I pre or append something it moves every element from every hotel into every element.

So I'm trying to only pre/append from a class name to a class name if it's with in a parent of the class name.

The class name of each hotel is .hotel:

```
$('.rating').prependTo(function(){
        $(this).parents('.hotel').prependTo('.price-tag');
});
```

This obviously isn't working, any help appreciated

Comment: can you share the html sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the `rating` to be prepended to the `price-tag` element within current `hotel`, in that case

```
$('.rating').each(function () {
   $(this).closest('.hotel').find('.price-tag').prepend(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    $('.rating').prependTo(function(){
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('hotel'))
        {
          $(this).prependTo('.price-tag');
        }
    });
```